# Extension method not found in the extended class

Tags: dart

I am having this simple code, where I want to use the extension method within the Test Class.

Although I am not getting any code errors I am getting a compiling error.

I run this on https://dartpad.dartlang.org/ but got the following error:

`Error compiling to JavaScript: main.dart:7:21: Error: Method not found: 'isTrue'. bool isItThough = isTrue(); ^^^^^^ Error: Compilation failed.`

```
void main() {
   //print(Test().isTrue);
  print(Test().isItThough);
}

class Test {
  bool isItThough = isTrue();
}

extension on Test {
  bool isTrue() => true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you try to paste this code not in DartPad but IDE so may see a warning

```
The instance member 'isTrue' can't be accessed in an initializer.
```

so, as option, you can modify the code like this

```
class Test {
  bool get isItThough => isTrue();
}
```

Comment: Correct. Extension methods are invoked on instances of the `on` type, and field initializers are run in a static context where there is no `this` instance.